# Having a list of #define replacements for values, how to resolve a value into a string of the identifier?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

While adapting some given interface, I came across the problem of extending the use of a header file with a lot of `#defines`.

What I have is something like this:

```
#define STATUS_OK      0x00
#define STATUS_FAIL    0x01
#define STATUS_WAIT    0x02
#define STATUS_ILLEGAL 0x03
#define STATUS_FULL    0x04
...
```

There are a lot of definitions like this, and I am quite happy about it, because I didn't had to write them all.

However, while I can nicely use them for `switch`, `if` and other statements as a replacement for `0x00` and so on, I now would like to have the opposide direction.

So, having `0x00`, I would like to print out the identifier "STATUS_OK".

As far as I know, this is not possible, but what would be a good workaround to make it possible?! Would it be possible to setup an array like this:

```
arrayNames[STATUS_OK] = _STATUS_OK_
```

Whereby `STATUS_OK` would resolve to `0x00` and `_STATUS_OK_` would resolve to "STATUS_OK"?

Further, I am looking for a solution, which uses as little memory, as possible to do this.

This would be what I would like to be able to do:

```
prinf("%s",resolve(0x00));
-> "STATUS_OK"
```

I hope, I made clear what I am looking for.

*Edit:*

Thanks to all for, the quick and useful responses! I'll work with Larsmans solution and might try to combine it with the one of qrdl. May take a while, I'll replace this edit, when it is done.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a little macro wizardry and a *stringize* operator of the preprocessor to do it. Take a look:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define STATUS_OK 0x05
#define STATUS_BAD 0x09
#define LOOKUP_CASE(x) case x: return #x

const char *lookup_name(int val) {
    switch(val) {
        LOOKUP_CASE(STATUS_OK);
        LOOKUP_CASE(STATUS_BAD);
        default: return "<UNDEFINED>";
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(void) {
    printf("%s\n", lookup_name(STATUS_OK));
    printf("%s\n", lookup_name(STATUS_BAD));
    return 0;
}
```

The example is self-explanatory, except for the `LOOKUP_CASE` macro. It uses the `#` operator to produce a string constant that corresponds to its operand, letting you avoid repeating the name of the `#define`-d constant twice.

Here is a [link to ideone](http://ideone.com/VyGxz1) with this working example.

Comment: just beautiful! thanks! now that is going to be a hard decision against the solution from Larsman/qrdl. Unfortunately, it'll have to wait till tomorrow - calling it a day now. If anyone can add some comparitive analysis of the given solutions, I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 2):

Use [X-Macros](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/the-x-macro/228700289), although it will require changing your original header file

Comment: very nice too, thank you for sharing! It would be even an idea to combine your attempt with Larsmans, to get to an very nice conversion routine.

Comment: +1, I actually use a variant of same to generate tables, including debug strings. (Also, you can use the same method to generate a switch, although this doesn't help readability much)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
const char *status_str(int s)
{
    switch(s)
    {
        case STATUS_OK:
            return "STATUS_OK";
        /* And so on and so forth */
    }
}
```

Comment: this is what I am currently doing - althoungh, not in such a neat function. However, I was not too happy about that, because I am somewhat paranoid, when thinking about "what could change?" On the upside, I could combine this with the rountines to handle changes of STATUS.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to get name of the identifier from its value. Because the identifiers are no longer available after the pre-processing and compiler has no knowledge about them.

However, you can try to store their names in an array or some other trick similar to that.

Comment: thought so too, thanks for ensuring me. I am still a bit wobbly about many details of C.

Answer (score 1):

One easy solution is to write two very simple code generators. If you store your identifiers in a text file with the simple format

```
identifier value
```

e.g.

```
STATUS_OK      0x00
STATUS_FAIL    0x01
```

then two simple Awk scripts can generate a header with the `#defines` and a C module with the strings from that. For the headers:

```
BEGIN {
   print("#ifndef _STATUSCODES_H");
   print("#define _STATUSCODES_H");
}

{ printf("#define %s %s\n", $1, $2) }

END { print("#endif"); }
```

For the mapping back to strings:

```
BEGIN {
    print("#include \"statuscodes.h\"");
    print("char const *status_string(int status)");
    print("{");
    print("    switch (status) {");
}

{ printf("      case %s: \"%s\"\n", $2, $1); }

END {
    print("    }");
    print("}");
}
```

Then let your `Makefile` generate the module and header when the table of identifiers changes.

Comment: now this looks very interesting! I would have all the strings and could automatically regenerate them, when something should change, and I would not have to use any functions to resolve them - nice!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a solution for your problem without using `switch` to check for every value or making a full list with the names:

```
char *s_names[] = {
    "STATUS_OK",
    "STATUS_FAIL",
    ...
}
```

Now you can simply access the strings by the index (which is the error code):

```
printf("%s", s_names[0x00]);      // prints "STATUS_OK"
printf("%s", s_names[STATUS_OK]); // prints "STATUS_OK" too
```

This will work if you have the value (or the macro) but if you don't want to waste so much space for a whole list you can use this macro:

```
#define MACRO_TO_STRING(x) #x
```

Now you can convert the macro to a string but not the value  to a string:

```
printf("%s", MACRO_TO_STRING(STATUS_OK)); // prints "STATUS_OK"
printf("%s", MACRO_TO_STRING(0x00));      // but this doesn't work: prints "0x00"
```

Comment: thanks, but the main disadvantage in your array-solution would be the fixed arrangement - what if OK would be `0x00` and FAIL would be `0xFF`? Your second solution looks more promising, however, I think dasblinkenlight took this attempt to the next level.

Comment: Well, I thought every macro's value is one more than the previous.

Comment: Ok that was misleading from my side. In the cases where there are no numbering jumps this is helpful. Further, I found another situation, where this `MACRO_TO_STRING(x) #x` is quite nice.